# Converting negative milliseconds into human readable format in PHP

Tags: php, time, converters, notation, negative-number

Ok, so I have this function:

```
function convertTime($ms){

    $sec = floor($ms/1000);
    $ms = $ms % 1000;

    $min = floor($sec/60);
    $sec = $sec % 60;
    $t = $sec;

    $hr = floor($min/60);
    $min = $min % 60;
    $t = $min;

    $day = floor($hr/60);
    $hr = $hr % 60;
    $t = $hr . " h " . $t . " m";

    return $t;
}
```

It converts milliseconds into h:m and it works great with positive numbers.
Example:

```
echo convertTime(60000);       // outputs: 0 h 1 m
echo convertTime(60000*70);    // outputs: 1 h 10 m
echo convertTime(60000*60*48); // outputs: 48 h 0 m
```

(I dont want it to convert to days so its great that it shows the actual number of hours)
Unfortunately, it doesnt work very well with negative numbers...

```
echo convertTime(-60000);    //outputs: -1 h -1 m (should be 0 h -1 m)
```

Any ideas on how to compensate for this?

Comment: What do you want to have as a result? 1h 1m or 22h 59m?

Comment: echo convertTime(-60000); // Should output: 0 h -1 m

Comment: how about `echo "-".convertTime(60000);` :P

Comment: @jurgemaister That won't work for higher `$ms` - the result then could be like `-12 h 54 m`...

Comment: @Alice You have an error in Your algorithm: the days should be computed like `$day = floor($hr / 24);` coz one day has 24 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your original function, formatted, unnecessary lines removed and three lines added:

```
function convertTime($ms)
{
    $sign = $ms < 0 ? "-" : "";
    $ms = abs($ms);
    $sec = floor($ms / 1000);
    $ms = $ms % 1000;
    $min = floor($sec / 60);
    $sec = $sec % 60;
    $hr = floor($min / 60);
    $min = $min % 60;
    $day = floor($hr / 60);
    $hr = $hr % 60;
    return "$sign$hr h $min m";
}
echo convertTime(+60000);      //  0 h 1 m
echo convertTime(-60000);      // -0 h 1 m
echo convertTime(-60000 * 60); // -1 h 0 m
```

Here is my version of the same function:

```
function convertTime($ms)
{
    $xx = $ms < 0 ? "-" : "+";
    $ms = abs($ms);
    $ss = floor($ms / 1000);
    $ms = $ms % 1000;
    $mm = floor($ss / 60);
    $ss = $ss % 60;
    $hh = floor($mm / 60);
    $mm = $mm % 60;
    $dd = floor($hh / 24);
    $hh = $hh % 24;
    return sprintf("%s%dd %02dh %02dm %02d.%04ds", $xx, $dd, $hh, $mm, $ss, $ms);
}
```

Comment: I think it is silly to say `-0 h -1 m` or `0 h -1 m`. The code can of course be modified to match the posted output.

Comment: Thank you for trying Salman, but unfortunately this doesnt work for me. echo convertTime(-60000); outputs -0d 00h 01m 00.0000s

Comment: Use the first example, ignore the second.

Comment: You're right about that minus sign tho, it does look dumb.
How can we make it always appear in the beginning of the string and not in front of minute?

`echo convertTime(-59*60*1000); // Should output - 0 h 59 m
echo convertTime(-61*60*1000); // Should output - 1 h 1 m`